# What is the Time Complexity of Initializing a 2D Array of Primitives in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, initialization, time-complexity

I'm working on a project using Java and am creating an object which has a 2D array of primitive values as one of its instance variables. I'm hoping to create a method which initializes the object's instance variables in *O(n)* time complexity, but I'm unsure if this is possible as my understanding of 2D array initialization is that it takes *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, as a 2D array is essentially an array of arrays, and initializing a 1D array in Java takes *O(n)* time. I was hoping to confirm whether or not this belief and reasoning is correct.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `O(n^2)` is correct for an array of dimensions `[n][n]`. But I'm curious why it matters.

Comment: @shmosel Thank you very much. To be honest, it really doesn't in this specific case: the 2D array I'm creating is 6 x 7, so it's small enough where it wouldn't make much of a difference. The main reason I asked is because I'm trying to learn efficient coding practices, and I'm practicing by trying to keep my methods and functions at a maximum time complexity of O(n log n) whenever possible.

Comment: ["*premature optimization is the root of all evil*" -- Donald Ervin Knuth: *Computer Programming as an Art* (1974), p. 671](https://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=361612&ftid=289767)

Comment: Time complexity is O(n) if there are n elements total. There is nothing special about a 2D array

Comment: A tip: a homogenous matrix of _n_ rows and  _m_  columns can be represented as a 1d array of _n * m_ elements. Imagine laying all of the rows end to end. Instead of accessing elements as `array[i][j]`, you can access them as `array[i * n + j]`.